# Authenticating my Asp.net mvc users from another system

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a CRM system named “MSP ServiceDesk plus” that uses its own form authentication. I am going to extend this CRM system by building asp.net mvc application that connect to the CRM database and uses its APIs. But is there a way y to integrate my default asp.net mvc form authentication module to use the CRM database so that all the users will still be managed from the CRM system.
Any advice on how to implement this.
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is by implementing a custom asp.net membership provider.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

I think you will only need to implement a couple of the provided methods, because you only want to authenticate the users in your app, and not create, edit or update them.
I've done this before in a situation like yours and it's pretty straightforward.